# Cannot view RSS Feed on Firefox Mobile "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it."

Tags: android, xml, firefox, rss, yahoo-finance

I am writing an application that needs to provide links to company/industry news on Yahoo Finance from within the application.

All I need to do is provide a link to `https://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline`, and include the stock symbol in the GET parameters, such as:

https://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=YHOO (for the company "YHOO")

In Firefox (desktop version), this url loads with nice clickable news links. HOWEVER, on Firefox Mobile (Android) or really any other Android browser, I get the message:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it.
The document tree is shown below.
```

and an ugly XML file with non-clickable links.

Is there any way to make the Yahoo feed load with pretty, clickable headlines on Android mobile devices? PLEASE NOTE: I'm not interested in *subscribing* to any of these feeds. I simply want to open up the Yahoo RSS url in a new tab, see what the latest news is for any given stock symbol, and be able to click on THOSE links, from either the desktop or mobile. Is there any way to accomplish this? If not, is there a better Yahoo Finance url with human readable news that I can use?

EDIT: I realize I could fetch the data from the URL, parse the XML file, and display the news links in my own application, but I'm really just looking for the quickest, easiest solution. This is a personal project that I don't have much time for. For example, is there an add-on for Firefox Mobile that will display it the same way as it does on the desktop?

Comment: It's an RSS feed. It's not meant to be read directly by humans. You use an RSS reader for that. You could provide your own XSLT to transform the XML into a nice HTML document and view that, but that's something YOU have to do.

Comment: @MarcB But is that something I can do for an RSS feed from another company's web site?

Comment: compare the raw xml from both. the working one will probably have some extra stuff to specify an xslt.

Answer (score 0):

In the desktop version at least, the [Feed View addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/feed-preview/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) fixes the problem. ([reference](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=318028))

Another solution and explanation [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/915992). The explanation:

> That usually means that the server doesn't send the file with the
> correct required MIME (content) type.
>
> In this case the file is send as text/xml instead of
> application/rss+xml or application/xhtml+xml